# Specific deploy magento view files

Tags: css, custom-theme, magento2.4.2

I'm trying run two step below

**step1:**

```
rm -rf pub/static/* ./var/view_preprocessed/* ./var/page_cache/* ./var/cache/* ./var/generation/*
```

**step2:**

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Nature/CustomTheme`

But in real process another theme like: `Magento/Luma` and `Magento/Blank` still run deploy.
What should we do to deploy specific theme ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, your theme is based on Luma, which means Luma will be deployed as well and since Luma is implemented on top of Blank, Blank theme is deployed also.

This is a normal behavior related to theme inheritance.

Comment: Tks but i'm using window platfom try to learn Magento and my purpose is make the process still exactly and faster.I think no problem in the linux enviroment.

Comment: I'm trying remove My theme don't do it with Magento folder in /pub/static and the process faster alot when needn't recerate many files in its.

Comment: I think it's important that you understand how this works. **In your custom theme you don't have everything you need to render all the Magento functionalities. In Blank you do, and Luma, which is built on top of Blank contains only a subset of overwrites.** The idea is that all 3 of these assets are deployed and a combination of rendering assets is compiled from all 3 of them according to the overwrites instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome! Feel free to mark the answer as solution so others can see it too and I wish you good luck in learning the mysterious ways of Magento :)

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean can you help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/332953/77554 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @Diana Botean as your Theme is based on luma and luma is based on blank so it will load luma as well as blank theme.

And It didn't whether it a window or Linux Magento have the same behavior.

If you don't want to both luma as well as the blank theme to get deploy by creating your own theme independent of other

I believe then also you might require a blank theme.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Tkank you somuch, i can understands more and more at the first day with magento.

Comment: No need of thanks, Once you learn then start helping other that what developer do